# How to find a spreadsheet to which a form submits?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

In my organization, we have recently found a form that is supposed to collect some kind of submissions from people. The problem is that we don't know who exactly created it and where are the answers stored. Is there a way to locate the spreadsheet from the form alone?

Answer (score 1):

If your org. uses domain, (i.e. form created not by gmail user) you can see author, and your admin can reset password for that account and acces it.

Answer (score -1):

No, that is not possible, unless you will use an account that created that Google Form.